# Same Image Files for iPad & 3.5" Retina

Tags: ios, ipad

How can i use the same images (not just backgrounds) for iPad & 3.5" Retina?

They are of similar resolutions , and should be ok to use them as they are in both  - seems a waste to use both as duplicates and different names. Currently when i try that , the images are appearing very small on the ipad ... Why is that happening and how to solve it ?

Note - Using cocos2d

Answer (score 0):

Use double resolution Image for Retina dislay.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        Bg=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Main_Screen_BG.png"];
        Bg.position=ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
        Bg.scaleX = screenSize.width / Bg.contentSize.width;
        Bg.scaleY = screenSize.height / Bg.contentSize.height;
        [self addChild:Bg z:-1];
```

here Bg is the background sprite

also for other images you can scale them.